# BinaryTree Node Class in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am trying to build a node class for binary tree implementation. Here is the header file for Node class:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(int value);
    void setParent(Node& parent);
    void setLeftChild(Node& child);
    void setRightChild(Node& child);
    void setValue(int value);
    void setIndex(int index);
    void setHeight(int height);
private:
    int value;
    Node& parent;
    Node& leftChild;
    Node& rightChild;
    int height;
    int index;
};
```

Now, I want to write the constructor Node(int value) declared above.
How shall I initialize the leftChild, rightChild, parent fields? They are also Node(s), so I want to call default constructor on them but it does not seem to work.
    Node::Node(int value) : value(value), parent(), leftChild(), rightChild(){
    }

Compiler is saying that "reference to type 'Node' needs an initializer"

Thanks.

Comment: References need to refer to an object. So you need an object for them to refer to.

Comment: A reference needs to be bound to an already existing object.

Comment: There is no point in all those setters (even if they were possible, but you can never set a references), just make the data member public directly. Alternatively (better), make the method building the tree a friend... Also, if the children are neighbours to each other, then just one pointer to the first child suffices, the right child is just next to it (`child[0]`, `child[1]`)

Comment: Thanks guys! Problem solved. I keep using references when I should use pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a constructor which specify the parent of the node:
        Node(Node *parent, int value);
 When you create the root node you simply call this contructor with NULL as parameter.
All the reference to parent and childs should be pointers.

Comment: Yes, pointers! Java makes me used to references while in c++, the counterpart is pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could better use pointers (`Node*`) instead of references (`Node&`). And in constructor just assign `nullptr` to them.

References are neccessary to reference some object (and obviously when you don't have a left or right child you can't reference them). So pointers come here to help you - they allow point to nothing - in this case `nullptr` is used as nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it makes sense to use pointers over references and initialize them to NULL. By doing this you may also check if a node has a child or parent (i.e. is not root node) by checking for a NULL pointer. Also, be sure to add a destructor to deallocate memory.